# How can I add a fixed string to an imask field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imaskjs

In the [documentation](https://imask.js.org/) we have the following example:

```
var phoneMask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('phone-mask'), {
    mask: '+{7}(000)000-00-00'
});
```

I know I can fix characters using `{}`, but I'm struggling to do this:

`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@test.com.br`

Adding the custom characters in the 'x' places. Is it possible?